# Parsing and extracting data from a file in python

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I have searched quite a bit on this topic, and have learned quite a bit so far. I am still new to python, and I know there is an easy way to parse data with the csv module. So, I have data that looks like this:

```
Date        MaxT  MinT  Pcpn  Snow  Snwg  
01/01/1948    34    13  0.00   0.0     T  
01/02/1948    46    29  0.01   0.0     T  
01/03/1948    38    16     T     T     T  
01/04/1948    38    15  0.00   0.0     T  
01/05/1948    44    15  0.00   0.0     T  
01/06/1948    42    23  0.00   0.0     T
```

which is daily weather data for every day of the year until the end of the record.  Most times the end of the record is present day.  I can parse this out and extract data from it, but my main problem and reason for the question is how do I extract and save data based upon specific dates?

For example, if I wanted the maximum temperature that occurred for April 25 out of all the years in the record, and the year it happened, how exactly do I isolate specific dates and only use max() or min() on that date, not all days of the year?  I want my program to search through every single date of the year, and find max and min values for each respective date along with the year it happened, and save them for later use.

Eventually, I want to get the highest and lowest maxT and minT (highest maxT, lowest minT, highest minT, lowest minT) for each location, the years each value occurred, and combine specific dates together.  That way I have a file for all 365 days of the year containing locations and the 4 extreme values with the years each happened.  I can handle getting the locations together and making new files, but for now, I need to figure out how to get just the extremes for each day of the year.

When its all said and done, my output header should look like this and have a file for each day of the year:

```
Location HighMax year LowMax year HighMin year LowMin year
```

Comment: Pandas module is what you want

Comment: why can't you use a database?. It seems it is good option for your requirement.

Comment: I agree with @thavan.  Or, simpler yet, you could just import the data into a spreadsheet app.

Comment: But I have hundreds of locations that have up to 125 years of data, and I want to find the values for each of the locations then combine the results into 366 different files for the daily extremes.

Answer (score 0):

Give [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) a try:

test.csv:

```
Date,MaxT,MinT,Pcpn,Snow,Snwg
01/01/1948,34,13,0.00,0.0,T
01/02/1948,46,29,0.01,0.0,T
01/03/1948,38,16,T,T,T
01/04/1948,38,15,0.00,0.0,T
01/05/1948,44,15,0.00,0.0,T
01/06/1948,42,23,0.00,0.0,T
```

Read the csv, set the `Date` as the index

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [4]: df = pd.read_csv('test.csv').set_index('Date')

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
            MaxT  MinT  Pcpn Snow Snwg
Date                                  
01/01/1948    34    13  0.00  0.0    T   
01/02/1948    46    29  0.01  0.0    T   
01/03/1948    38    16     T    T    T   
01/04/1948    38    15  0.00  0.0    T   
01/05/1948    44    15  0.00  0.0    T   
01/06/1948    42    23  0.00  0.0    T
```

`Pandas` provide a nice structrue `DataFrame` to manipulate your data. For example, to get the max `MaxT`:

```
In [9]: index = df['MaxT'].idxmax() 
In [11]: index, df['MaxT'][index]
Out[11]: ('01/02/1948', 46)
```

It should take you some times to learn `pandas`. 
If your job is highly reliable on these kind of data, it's worth learn.

Comment: You could modify your example to use the OP's delimiter.